# Wordpress not showing the_title()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
         <?php

              $post = get_post_meta($post->ID);
              $img = $post['image_url'][0];
              $web = $post['website_url'][0];
              echo get_the_title();
              the_title();
              the_content();

          ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm trying display title, content is displaying ok, but is something wrong with title. I try `the_title();` and  `get_the_title();` but both not work.

**Problem is in:**

```
$post = get_post_meta($post->ID); 
                  $img = $post['image_url'][0];
                  $web = $post['website_url'][0];
```

if I remowe , post title displaying ok .

Comment: did you do `var_dump(get_the_title());` or `var_dump(the_title());` to see if they both contain a value?

Comment: any plugin that could modify title ?

Comment: No all plugins deactived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you gen an error when you use get_post_meta. You are providing to the function only the post id, you also need to provide the key.

You should use it like this:

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```